# Gatling. ConnectException: connection timed out:

Tags: scala, testing, intellij-idea, load, gatling

I'm new in gatling and now experimenting with Gatling on its website  computer-database.gatling.io.

Everything is working fine and i'm going to apply load test for my project at work in few days, but one problem, 
I need 2000 users/per second for my website (it seems not a big deal for gatling as I read on other recourses)

I have this simple code:  where I want to load 250 users/admins during 300 seconds, and now issues and questions (Please, help me figure this out)
When I've started this script:

```
package load

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.structure.ChainBuilder
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef.jdbcFeeder
import scala.util.Random
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class TestOvo extends Simulation {
 val httpProtocol = http
 .baseURL("http://computer-database.gatling.io")
 .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8")
 .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
 .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.8")
 .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36")

 val headers_0 = Map("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" -> "1")

 val headers_10 = Map(
 "Origin" -> "http://computer-database.gatling.io",
 "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" -> "1")

 object Search {
 val search = exec(http("request_0")
 .get("/")
 .headers(headers_0))
 .pause(1)
 .exec(http("request_1")
 .get("/computers?f=macbook")
 .headers(headers_0))
 .pause(2)
 .exec(http("request_2")
 .get("/computers/89")
 .headers(headers_0))
 .pause(2)
 .exec(http("request_3")
 .get("/")
 .headers(headers_0))
 .pause(2)
 }
 object Browse {
 val browse = exec(http("request_4")
 .get("/computers?p=1")
 .headers(headers_0))
 .pause(1)
 .exec(http("request_5")
 .get("/computers?p=2")
 .headers(headers_0))
 .pause(1)
 .exec(http("request_6")
 .get("/computers?p=3")
 .headers(headers_0))
 .pause(2)
 .exec(http("request_7")
 .get("/computers?p=4")
 .headers(headers_0)
 .resources(http("request_8")
 .get("/computers?p=5")
 .headers(headers_0)))
 .pause(1)
 }

 object Edit {
 val edit = exec(http("request_9")
 .get("/computers/new")
 .headers(headers_0))
 .pause(1)
 .exec(http("request_10")
 .post("/computers")
 .headers(headers_10)
 .formParam("name", "VoxooBox")
 .formParam("introduced", "12.11.2017")
 .formParam("discontinued", "")
 .formParam("company", "16")
 .check(status.is(400)))
 .pause(1)
 .exec(http("request_11")
 .post("/computers")
 .headers(headers_10)
 .formParam("name", "VoxooBox")
 .formParam("introduced", "2017.08.17")
 .formParam("discontinued", "")
 .formParam("company", "16")
 .check(status.is(400)))
 .pause(1)
 .exec(http("request_12")
 .post("/computers")
 .headers(headers_10)
 .formParam("name", "VoxooBox")
 .formParam("introduced", "2017-08-17")
 .formParam("discontinued", "")
 .formParam("company", "16"))
 }

 val users = scenario("Users").exec(Search.search, Browse.browse);
 val admins = scenario("Admins").exec(Search.search, Browse.browse, Edit.edit);

 setUp(
 users.inject(constantUsersPerSec(200) during (300 seconds)),
 admins.inject(constantUsersPerSec(50) during (300 seconds))
 ).protocols(httpProtocol)

}
```

it goes maximum to indicator of users:

```
================================================================================
2017-10-17 14:47:20                                          25s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------ 

> Global                                                   (OK=15950  KO=0     ) 

> request_0                                                (OK=5046   KO=0     ) 

> request_0 Redirect 1                                     (OK=3829   KO=0     ) 

> request_1                                                (OK=2582   KO=0     ) 

> request_2                                                (OK=1589   KO=0     ) 

> request_3                                                (OK=1249   KO=0     ) 

> request_3 Redirect 1                                     (OK=897    KO=0     ) 

> request_4                                                (OK=423    KO=0     ) 

> request_5                                                (OK=224    KO=0     ) 

> request_6                                                (OK=88     KO=0     ) 

> request_7                                                (OK=17     KO=0     ) 

> request_8                                                (OK=6      KO=0     )

---- Users ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[------                                                                    ]  0%

          waiting: 55156  / active: 4842   / done:2     
---- Admins --------------------------------------------------------------------
[------                                                                    ]  0%

          waiting: 13788  / active: 1212   / done:0     
================================================================================

14:47:21.107 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'request_5' failed: j.n.ConnectException: connection timed out: computer-database.gatling.io/35.158.229.206:80
```

And then arise these kind of errors:

[WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'request_4' failed: j.n.ConnectException: connection timed out: computer-database.gatling.io/35.158.229.206:80
13:31:12.407 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'request_4' failed: j.n.ConnectException: Failed to open a socket.

In gatling.conf I found these rows:

```
ahc {
  #keepAlive = true                                # Allow pooling HTTP connections (keep-alive header automatically added)
  #connectTimeout = 10000                          # Timeout when establishing a connection
  #handshakeTimeout = 10000                        # Timeout when performing TLS hashshake
  #pooledConnectionIdleTimeout = 60000             # Timeout when a connection stays unused in the pool
  #readTimeout = 60000                             # Timeout when a used connection stays idle
  #maxRetry = 2                                    # Number of times that a request should be tried again
  #requestTimeout = 60000                          # Timeout of the requests
  #acceptAnyCertificate = true                     # When set to true, doesn't validate SSL certificates
  #httpClientCodecMaxInitialLineLength = 4096      # Maximum length of the initial line of the response (e.g. "HTTP/1.0 200 OK")
  #httpClientCodecMaxHeaderSize = 8192             # Maximum size, in bytes, of each request's headers
  #httpClientCodecMaxChunkSize = 8192              # Maximum length of the content or each chunk
  #webSocketMaxFrameSize = 10240000                # Maximum frame payload size
```

i guess it may be somehow related to my issue, or what i'm doing wrong? Is that my side-issue or their website just can't take it?

And why when I launch

```
users.inject(constantUsersPerSec(200) during (300 seconds)),
 admins.inject(constantUsersPerSec(50) during (300 seconds))
```

In terminal it's

```
waiting: 55156  / active: 4842   / done:2
 waiting: 13788  / active: 1212   / done:0
```

so many? How is it calculated? or why at all, explain someone to me, please.
Thanks.

My Computer:
MAC OS
Version: 10.12.6 (
Processor: 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory: 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Comment: I'm afraid you're not understanding `constantUsersPerSec` right: `constantUsersPerSec(200) during (300 seconds)` means 200 * 300 = 60.000 users at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`constantUsersPerSec()` is about the number of users you're injecting, not the number of total users.

`constantUsersPerSec(200) during (300 seconds)`, that's 60k users. So, that matches with `waiting: 55156  / active: 4842 / done:2`= 60k users.

I think that what you actually want is to inject users using the following strategy: `rampUsers(10) over (300 seconds)`

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually I need to inject that number of users in order to get 2000r/per second, hot do it better? via constant users where 2000 will start from the beginning or via ramp where the number of users will be increasing stage by stage?

Comment: Perhaps with `.throttle()`? https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup/#throttling